# How can I pass a complex objects as input when using Cadence HTTP API tool?

Tags: go, cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

Here is a sample workflow and its input struct:

```
func MyWorkflow(ctx cadence.Context, input MyInput) error {
    ...
}

type MyInput struct {
    SomeString: string,
    SomeInteger: int
}
```

According to Cadence HTTP API [documentation](https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/concepts/http-api/#using-http-api), workflow can be started by sending a HTTP POST request with the payload like below:

```
{
  "domain": "sample-domain",
  "workflow_id": "sample-workflow-id",
  "execution_start_to_close_timeout": "61s",
  "task_start_to_close_timeout": "60s",
  "workflow_type": {
    "name": "sample-workflow-type"
  },
  "task_list": {
    "name": "sample-task-list"
  },
  "identity": "client-name-visible-in-history",
  "request_id": "8049B932-6C2F-415A-9BB2-241DCF4CFC9C",
  "input": {
    "data": "IkN1cmwhIg=="
  }
}
```

When I tried to start the workflow through HTTP API with the above payload, the workflow failed immediately and gave this error:

```
{
  "reason": "cadenceInternal:Generic",
  "details": "unable to decode the workflow function input bytes with error: unable to decode argument: 0, *MyInput, with json error: EOF, function name: sample-workflow-type",
}
```

From my understanding, it failed because it cannot decode bytes into the type MyInput.

I tried to change the input type to byte array:

```
func MyWorkflow(ctx cadence.Context, input []byte) error {
}
```

However, when I tried to read different input, it is always return 0 for the length.

```
func MyWorkflow(ctx cadence.Context, input []byte) error {
    // output 0 for length of input
    logger.Info("length of input", zap.Int("length", len(input))
}
```

Could someone let me know what I did wrong here please? Thanks in advance!